# Allow to check 2nd checkbox if first is checked in JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two checkboxes and my scenario is "if first checkbox is checked then allow user to check 2nd checkbox otherwise 2nd checkbox should not to be checked." 

                                
                                          Audition Done

```
                               </td>
                        </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td style="width: 30%" align="right" class="label" nowrap="noWrap" valign="top">
                                      Audition Approved
                                         </td>
                            <td style="width: 70%" align="left" class="label" nowrap="noWrap" valign="top">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAuditionApproved"  onclick="checkboxCheck();" runat="server" />

                               </td>
                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   
       $(function () {
            $("#chkAuditionApproved").click(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chkbox2").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("#chkbox2").focus();
                } else {
                  $('#chkbox2').prop('checked', false);
                    $("#chkbox2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkAuditionApproved" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox2" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAuditionDone" runat="server" />
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAuditionApproved" onclick="checkboxCheck();" runat="server" />

                              $(function () {
            $("#chkAuditionDone").click(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chkAuditionApproved").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("#chkAuditionApproved").focus();
                } else {
                    $("#chkAuditionApproved").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
        });

Comment: i tried but when i clik to check first then not anable 2nd one for clickable

Comment: First Disable the 2nd Checkbox and Check the ID using Inspect element, since you had used runat="server" ID will change